# Is it possible to find the subnet mask of a user with PHP?

Tags: php, networking, ip

I have created a website for the company where I work.
I would like to restrict access to the user preset with subnet mask. Is this possible with PHP?. The IP is known.

Comment: Why ce this such une Mischmasch of languages?

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake on my part

Comment: Still... "Subnetzmaske"?

Comment: Ooookay.... the English speakers on here (i.e. most) would probably prefer the English term though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you've asked the question? No. You cannot determine the client's subnet mask from the server side.

You *can*, however, define your own network and mask on the server side to match client IPs against to determine whether or not to grant access. You should first [read up on how subnetting works](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/workingwithipaddresses/a/subnetmask.htm), then use the [`ip2long()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) function and [bitwise operations](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) to grant access to particular network segments.

Honestly though, the majority of the time when you want to restrict access by IP address you're going to want to do this at the network/firewall level, not in the application.

Comment: I agree with Sammitch. I've posted an answer with a function to use ip2long to determine network segments, but this is definitely the kind of thing best done on the network hardware and not in the application itself.  Case in point, what happens when your network topology changes, and all of the sudden you have to remember where to change your application to keep things working?

Answer (score 0):

That's easy: The "subnet" mask for a given IP address is `255.255.255.255`.

---

The subnet mask together with a subnet defines a range a ip addresses.

So, to gather the subnet mask from an ip address you need the subnet.

---

My somehow ironical answer above assumes that subnet and ip address are the same. Which technical is not possible, as all 4x255 bits are used for the subnet and no more bits are available for any ip address.

Comment: Downvoted? What am I missing, please?

Comment: The subnet mask for a given IP is not 255.255.255.255.  These are octets of numbers that split the IP into two separate addresses.  For example, a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 is the address 11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000, which means that every bit in the first three octets describes the network address and every bit in the last octet describes the host address.  Given two or more host addresses, it is possible to determine if they exist on the same subnet mask.

Comment: You are right. A subnet mask of 255.255.255.255 would not allow any valid ip address. So seen it this way my answer is wrong. Anyhow this **is** a special case. If the value of a subnet mask is reduced to a bit mask marking constant bits in an ip address one could put it the way I did, although calling it subnet mask then is not correct. @JoshuaKaiser

Answer (score -1):

I believe this might do what you are trying to achieve:

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Check if a client IP is in our Server subnet
 *
 * @author david dot schueler at tel-billig dot de
 * @param string $client_ip
 * @param string $server_ip
 * @return boolean
 */
function clientInSameSubnet($client_ip=false,$server_ip=false) {
    if (!$client_ip)
        $client_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    if (!$server_ip)
        $server_ip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
    // Extract broadcast and netmask from ifconfig
    if (!($p = popen("ifconfig","r"))) return false;
    $out = "";
    while(!feof($p))
        $out .= fread($p,1024);
    fclose($p);
    // This is because the php.net comment function does not
    // allow long lines.
    $match  = "/^.*".$server_ip;
    $match .= ".*Bcast:(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}i\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).*";
    $match .= "Mask:(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})$/im";
    if (!preg_match($match,$out,$regs))
        return false;
    $bcast = ip2long($regs[1]);
    $smask = ip2long($regs[2]);
    $ipadr = ip2long($client_ip);
    $nmask = $bcast & $smask;
    return (($ipadr & $smask) == ($nmask & $smask));
}
?>
```